# Dar salida a shiny a través del puerto 80 vía Apache

Tags: r, apache, shiny

Necesito dar salida a una app creada mediante Shiny en R Studio, la misma debería ser por "puerto 80" vía Apache.
¿Alguien podría orientarme en cómo realizar esto? Estoy siguiendo algunas consignas aprendiendo en el uso de la herramienta.